# How to unit test web service with Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, unit-testing

I have a web service, which I would like to do some unit testing on, however I am not sure how I can do this.  Can anyone give any suggestions? Below is the webservice, it produces an object with three fields, but only when there is values in the database queue.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public CommandMessages GetDataLINQ()
    {
        CommandMessages result;
        using (var dc = new TestProjectLinqSQLDataContext())
        {
            var command = dc.usp_dequeueTestProject();
            result = command.Select(c => new CommandMessages(c.Command_Type, c.Command, c.DateTimeSent)).FirstOrDefault();
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, what you've posted can't really be Unit Tested at all; by definition, a Unit Test can have only a single reason to fail; However in your case, a single test of `GetDataLINQ()` (the "*System Under Test*" or "SUT") could fail because of a problem with any of the dependencies in the function - namely, `TestProjectLinqSQLDataContext` and `usp_dequeueTestProject`.

When you call this method from a Unit test, these dependencies at present are probably beyond your control because you didn't directly create them - they are most likely created in your page classes' constructor. (Note: this is an assumption on my part, and I could be wrong)

Also, because these dependencies are at present real "live" objects, which have hard dependencies on an actual database being present, it means your tests aren't able to run independently, which is another requirement for a Unit Test.

> (I'll assume your page's class file is "MyPageClass" from now on, and I will pretend it's not a web page code-behind or asmx code-behind; because as other posters have pointed out, this only matters in the context of accessing the code via HTTP which we're not doing here)

```
var sut = new MyPageClass(); //sut now contains a DataContext over which the Test Method has no control.
var result = sut.GetDataLINQ(); //who know what might happen?
```

Consider some possible reasons for failure in this method when you call `sut.GetDataLINQ()`:

- `new TestProjectLinqSQLDataContext()` results in an exception because of a fault in `TestProjectLinqSQLDataContext`'s constructor
- `dc.usp_dequeueTestProject()` results in an exception because the database connection fails, or because the stored procedure has changed, or doesn't exist.
- `command.Select(...)` results in an exception because of some as of yet unknown defect in the `CommandMessage` constructor
- Probably many more reasons (i.e failure to *perform correctly* as opposed to an exception being thrown)

> Because of the multiple ways to fail, you can't quickly and reliably tell what went wrong (certainly your test runner will indicate what type of exception threw, but that requires you to at least read the stack trace - you shouldn't need to do this for a Unit Test)

So, in order to do this you need to be able to setup your SUT - in this case, the `GetDataLINQ` function - such that any and all dependencies are fully under the control of the test method.

So if you really want to Unit Test this, you'll have to make some adjustments to your code. I'll outline the ideal scenario and then one alternative (of many) if you can't for whatever reason implement this. No error checking included in the code below, nor is it compiled so please forgive any typos, etc.

### Ideal scenario

Abstract the dependencies, and inject them into the constructor.

> Note that this ideal scenario will require you to introduce an IOC framework (Ninject, AutoFAC, Unity, Windsor, etc) into your project. It also requires a Mocking framework (Moq, etc).

### 1. Create an interface `IDataRepository`, which contains a method `DequeueTestProject`

```
public interface IDataRepository
{
     public CommandMessages DequeueTestProject();
}
```

### 2. Declare `IDataRepository` as a dependency of `MyPageClass`

```
 public class MyPageClass
    {
        readonly IDataRepository _repository;
        public MyPageClass(IDataRepository repository)
        {
             _repository=repository;
        }
    }
```

### 3. Create an actual implementation of `IDataRepository`, which will be used in "real life" but *not* in your Unit Tests

```
public class RealDataRepository: IDataRepository
{
    readonly MyProjectDataContext _dc;
    public RealDataRepository()
    {
        _dc = new MyProjectDataContext(); //or however you do it.
    }

    public CommandMessages DequeueTestProject()
    {
        var command = dc.usp_dequeueTestProject();
        result = command.Select(c => new CommandMessages(c.Command_Type, c.Command, c.DateTimeSent)).FirstOrDefault();
        return result;
    }
}
```

> This is where you will need to involve your IOC framework such that it can inject the correct `IDataRepository` (i.e `RealDataRepository`) whenever your `MyPageClass` is instantiated by the ASP.NET framework

### 4. Recode your `GetDataLINQ()` method to use the _`repository` member

```
public CommandMessages GetDataLINQ()
    {
        CommandMessages result;
        return _repository.DequeueTestProject();
    }
```

So what has this bought us? Well, consider now how you can test against the following specification for GetDataLINQ:

1. Must always invoke `DequeueTestProject`
2. Must return `NULL` if there is no data in the database
3. Must return a valid `CommandMessages` instance if there is data in the database.

### Test 1 - Must always invoke `DequeueTestProject`

```
public void GetDataLINQ_AlwaysInvokesDequeueTestProject()
{
    //create a fake implementation of IDataRepository
    var repo = new Mock<IDataRepository>();
    //set it up to just return null; we don't care about the return value for now
    repo.Setup(r=>r.DequeueTestProject()).Returns(null);
    //create the SUT, passing in the fake repository
    var sut = new MyPageClass(repo.Object);
    //call the method
    sut.GetDataLINQ();
    //Verify that repo.DequeueTestProject() was indeed called.
    repo.Verify(r=>r.DequeueTestProject(),Times.Once);
}
```

### Test 2 - Must return NULL if there is no data in the database

```
public void GetDataLINQ_ReturnsNULLIfDatabaseEmpty()
{
//create a fake implementation of IDataRepository
    var repo = new Mock<IDataRepository>();
    //set it up to return null; 
    repo.Setup(r=>r.DequeueTestProject()).Returns(null);
    var sut = new MyPageClass(repo.Object);
    //call the method but store the result this time:
    var actual = sut.GetDataLINQ();
    //Verify that the result is indeed NULL:
    Assert.IsNull(actual);
}
```

### Test 3 - Must return a valid `CommandMessages` instance if there is data in the database.

```
public void GetDataLINQ_ReturnsNCommandMessagesIfDatabaseNotEmpty()
{
//create a fake implementation of IDataRepository
    var repo = new Mock<IDataRepository>();
    //set it up to return null; 
    repo.Setup(r=>r.DequeueTestProject()).Returns(new CommandMessages("fake","fake","fake");
    var sut = new MyPageClass(repo.Object);
    //call the method but store the result this time:
    var actual = sut.GetDataLINQ();
    //Verify that the result is indeed NULL:
    Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
}
```

- Because we can Mock the `IDataRepository` interface, therfore we can completely control how it behaves.
- We could even make it throw an exception, if we needed to test how `GetDataLINQ` responds to unforseen results.
- This is the real benefit of abstracting your dependencies when it comes to Unit Testing (not to mention, it reduces coupling in your system because dependencies are not tied to a particular concrete type).

### Not Quite ideal method

Introducing an IOC framework into your project may be a non-runner, so here is one alternative which is a compromise. There are other ways as well, this is just the first that sprang to mind.

- Create the `IDataRepository` interface
- Create the `RealDataRepository` class
- Create other implementations of `IDataRepository`, which mimic the behaviour we created on the fly in the previous example. These are called stubs, and basically they are just classes with a single, predefined behaviour that *never changes*. This makes then ideal for testing, because you always know what will happen when you invoke them.

---

```
public class FakeEmptyDatabaseRepository:IDataRepository
{
  public CommandMessages DequeueTestProject(){CallCount++;return null;}
  //CallCount tracks if the method was invoked.
  public int CallCount{get;private set;}
}

public class FakeFilledDatabaseRepository:IDataRepository
{
  public CommandMessages DequeueTestProject(){CallCount++;return new CommandMessages("","","");}
  public int CallCount{get;private set;}
}
```

Now modify the `MyPageClass` as per the first method, except *do not declare `IDataRepository` on the constructor*, instead do this:

```
   public class MyPageClass
    {
       private IDataRepository _repository; //not read-only
       public MyPageClass()
       {
          _repository = new RealDataRepository();
       }

       //here is the compromise; this method also returns the original repository so you can restore it if for some reason you need to during a test method.
       public IDataRepository SetTestRepo(IDataRepository testRepo)
       {
          _repository = testRepo;
       }
    }
```

And finally, modify your unit tests to use `FakeEmptyDatabaseRepository` or `FakeFilledDatabaseRepository` as appropriate:

```
public void GetDataLINQ_AlwaysInvokesDequeueTestProject()
{
    //create a fake implementation of IDataRepository
    var repo = new FakeFilledDatabaseRepository();  
    var sut = new MyPageClass();
    //stick in the stub:
    sut.SetTestRepo(repo);
    //call the method
    sut.GetDataLINQ();
    //Verify that repo.DequeueTestProject() was indeed called.
    var expected=1;
    Assert.AreEqual(expected,repo.CallCount);
}
```

Note that this second scenario is not an ivory-tower-ideal scenario and doesn't lead to strictly pure Unit tests (i.e if there were a defect in `FakeEmptyDatabaseRepository` your test could also fail) but it's a pretty good compromise; however if possible strive to achieve the first scenario as it leads to all kinds of other benefits and gets you one step closer to truly SOLID code.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to consume your data over the WebService to Unit test it. You can just create another project in your solution with a reference to your WebService project and call directly the methods.

Comment: I don't really understand how I would call the method of the webservice? Sorry I am very new to unit testing.  As an example what would I do for the above code to unit test it?

Comment: A webservice method is a method like any other method. The only difference is the WebMethod attribute you put on top of it. However, an attribute is a metadata information. It has no impact on the functionnality itself but rather describe or extend functionalities. In the case of a Unit test, the important thing is the result of the method, and that is not impacted at all by the attribute.

Comment: Thank you for this, I'm sorry I still do not understand about how to do a unit test on the above method. The information depends on what is available in a SQL table so how can this be tested on?

Comment: In that case, you need to refactor your class to use an Abstract Factory. In the case of a Unit test context, you could simply pass a data context that will point to a test database, or simply a Mock of your context.

Answer (score 0):

I would change your Code as follows:

```
public class MyRepository
{       
     public CommandMessage DeQueueTestProject()
     {
        using (var dc = new TestProjectLinqSQLDataContext())
        {
            var results = dc.usp_dequeueTestProject().Select(c => new CommandMessages(c.Command_Type, c.Command, c.DateTimeSent)).FirstOrDefault();
            return results;
        }
     }
}
```

Then code your Web Method as:

```
[WebMethod]
public CommandMessages GetDataLINQ()
{
    MyRepository db = new MyRepository();
    return db.DeQueueTestProject();
}
```

Then Code your Unit Test:

```
    [Test]
    public void Test_MyRepository_DeQueueTestProject()
    {
        // Add your unit test using MyRepository
        var r = new MyRepository();

        var commandMessage = r.DeQueueTestProject();
        Assert.AreEqual(commandMessage, new CommandMessage("What you want to compare"));
    }
```

This allows your code to be reusable and is a common design pattern to have Data Repositories.  You can now use your Repository Library everywhere you need it and test it in only one place and it should be good everywhere you use it.  This way you don't have to worry about complicated tests calling WCF Services.  This is a good way of testing Web Methods.

This is just a short explanation and can be improved much more, but this gets you in the right direction in building your Web Services.